# How do I install GNU's 'make binary package' to android shell

Tags: linux, shell, android, make

I need `make` to install things, based on my current knowledge: I have reached a chicken and egg scenario.

I have root access to the filesystem and shell, but the native android shell does not come with `make`. I am a Bourne noob and I would like to learn how to install the `make` binary package. I also need to learn how to install `configure` and other basic development binary packages. However, I think I can figure it out if I start with `make`.

Preferably I could do this from the android device with files that I can drop into the file system.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly -- you want to use an Android device to develop, build, and install Android programs natively -- I think the Android package [Terminal IDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spartacusrex.spartacuside&hl=en) might contain what you're looking for.

If you become serious about this, you are strongly advised to also get yourself a Bluetooth keyboard.

Comment: Maybe I can install the Terminal IDE APP and use that to compile the `make` source from GNU? I feel like there is a more elegant, shell based solution out there..

Comment: The Terminal IDE package is a terminal plus a pile of development tools, including `make`.

Comment: bah. Terminal-IDE requires Android 2.3, my device is 2.2.

Comment: Drat, blast, and fie.  Not much I can help with there.

...Perhaps you can re-flash your device with CyanogenMod?